# Color a cell where the sum of the row reaches a certain value

Tags: excel, formatting, conditional-statements

I need to find out in which week a sum of working hours exceeds a certain amount of hours. I would like to color that certain cell.

[image]

Thanks in advance!
Tim

Comment: The picture has the information required. Why is this put on hold?

Comment: I've no idea (the question could be improved, but it's perfectly specific) - can closers comment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select B3:K3, starting from B3 (This is important because the conditional formatting requires relative references, and the formula is based on which cell is Active within the Selection)

Then Select Home > Conditional Formatting > New Rule

Choose "Use a formula to determine which cells to format"

Enter: `=AND(SUM($B$3:B3)>100,SUM($A$3:A3)<=100)`

Click Format and then go to Fill tab to set the formatting you want for the highlighted cell.

Click OK to close everything.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Conditional formatting is what you need. Simply select the whole row 3 and give it a try:

[Conditional formatting, entire row based](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10705856/conditional-formatting-entire-row-based)

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick for you:

- in your example, click on cell `B3`
- on the `Home` tab, click `Conditional Formatting`, and then `New Rule`
- click `Use a formula to determine which cells to format`
- in the `Formula` box enter:  `=(SUM($B3:B3)>100)`
- click `Format`, and in the `Font` tab, choose the color you want cell to change to
- click `OK`, `OK`
- right click cell `B3` and choose `Copy`
- highlight the range of cells `B3 to K3`
- right click the highlighted cells and choose `Paste Special`
- choose `Formats` and then click `OK`

Now, the cell that "made" the sum exceed 100 (and cells after that one) will change color depending on the values of the cells.  Note that the formula for Conditional Formatting automatically updated when we copied it, partly because of the *Absolute vs Relative $ references* in the formula.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to colour the cell where the sum of working hours exceeds 100 and not the cells to the right of it, would need

```
=AND(SUM($B3:B3)>100,SUM($B3:B3)-B3<=100)
```

Comment: Perfect, this was what I needed. Thanks!