# conditional formatting after selecting a cell from list

Tags: excel, formula, conditional-formatting

I want row of a table to get color after selecting a number in a cell of that row from list
I want row to have red color when we select 1 and blue color when we select 2 form dropdown list
thanks
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hnYve.png)

Comment: i tried format only cells that contain in conditional formatting but color is getting only to that cell not entire row how to do that?

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10705856/conditional-formatting-entire-row-based - several answers to choose from, I would use the accepted answer

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Isn't this the basis of conditional formatting? What does your conditional formatting look like?

Answer (score 0):

In your table select the first cell under col1.
go to conditional formatting > new rule > use a formula to determine which cells to format

in the format values where this formula is true textbox write the first cell of col1 like this `=$B5=1` and on the format select red fill. Important to unfreeze (remove the $ from row 5 in the reference so that the formatting can by copied down the other cells.

Then go to conditional formatting again and manage rules.
Select the rule you created and edit the apllies to textbox from `=$B$5` to `=$B$5:$E$8` to cover the whole line.

In your table now copy the entire first row which is now formatted and paste special formats only to all the lines of the table (including the first row you are copying from)

1 - Red is done.

Now you can either repeat the whole process for two OR go the existing rule and copy it and then edit the copy from 1 to 2 and format from red to blue.

End result should look like this
[image]